# Javascript element hiding not working

Tags: javascript, css, forms, show-hide

I tried to hide elements in my html form by defining a javascript function at the beginning of my page and calling it through a button's onclick attribute.  It seems like the browser (firefox 4.x) tries initially to hide the given element when I click the button, but then quickly reloads it.  Without the script, obviously, no attempt is made by the browser to hide the element.  Here is the pertinent code:

```
function showHide() {
document.getElementById('search').style.display = 'none';
}


<button onclick="showHide()">Advanced</button>
```

Does firefox default to what it finds in the css file instead of using the javascript modifications?

Edit #1:
First off, I am trying to get an  text edit field to disappear.  When I click on the "Advanced" button, it does disappear for a fraction of a second and then reappears.  I tried returning false at the end of showHide(), but that did nothing, and I tried onclick="return showHide();" but that didn't work as well.  I checked the css file, and there are no display: settings that could conflict with this.  I'll see if I can't get this up on my server in a few minutes and post the link.

Edit #2:  Thanks for the help.  Changing the type attribute of the button fixed the issue by preventing the button from defaulting to "submit," as suggested below.  This kept the form from being reloaded, which was causing the element to reappear every time it tried to go away.  Not something a beginner like me would have known.

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of `showHide()`

Comment: No, it definitely uses javascript modifications (possible unless your CSS has !important in it). You say that it hides it but then reloads? I don't really understand what you mean (can you give us a link to the page?). There seems to be something else going on here.

Comment: have you checked for any errors shown by firebug? it can help a lot sometimes.

Comment: reminder: you should mark @Lee's answer as correct  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html `<button>` element supports a `type` attribute.  If omitted, it defaults to `type="submit"`.  This causes the button to work exactly like an `<input type="submit" />`.

So... if your button is located inside a form, then clicking the button causes the click handler to run (calling showHide()), but *then* it submits the form.  It is the form submission that is causing the page reload.

To fix this, simply add the proper type to your button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="showHide()">Advanced</button>
```

Comment: @Adam - I'm glad I could help.  Would you mind marking the answer as accepted? (just click the green check-mark next to the answer).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something else going on in your page because the basic code works fine in Firefox and other browsers.  You can try the demo for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LpC36/.

I'd suggest you describe what else might be going on the page?  Other code?  CSS?  Other objects and interactions?  Form submission?  Try showing us the HTML.

For example, if the button is a submit button, it could be submitting a form and reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with scope. Try this out:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('search').style.display = 'none';">Advanced</button>
```

if it works you didn't declare your `showHide()` function in the right place. For example i can break @jfriend00 's example like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NYZrX/1/

this is one of this reasons it is bad practice to mix javascript in html code, it all needs to be in the global scope...